# How do i run a shell script inside docker-compose

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, travis-ci

I have a use case in which i am trying to build a django based rest api and then use continuous integration using travis CI when changes are pushed to github. I am also using docker to build and docker-compose to scale my services. The problem is i want to run pytest and flake8 when i push my changes to github. Now i have not added any tests and hence the pytest command is giving an exit status of 5.

To get around this i tried creating a script to do this :

```
#!/bin/bash

pytest;
err=$? ;
if (( $err != 5 )) ;
then
  exit $err;
fi
flake8 ;
```

But i cannot get docker-compose to run this . When i run the script using the command :

```
docker-compose run app sh -c "run_script.sh"
```

It gives the below error message :
sh: run_script.sh: not found

Below is my docker-compose yml file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

And below is the dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

MAINTAINER Subhayan Bhattacharya

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY Pipfile* /tmp/

RUN cd /tmp && pip install pipenv && pipenv lock --requirements > requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./app /app

RUN adduser -D user
USER user
```

This should be a simple issue but i cannot figure out how to get around this.

Can someone please help me find the solution

Comment: You should copy that file into your images too. `COPY script.sh /app/container_script.sh`. And make sure you've gave it execute permission already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script isn't working because Alpine base images don't have GNU bash.  Your script *almost* limits itself to the [POSIX Shell Command Language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18); if you do, you can change the "shebang" line to `#!/bin/sh`.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# ^^^ not bash
pytest    # individual lines don't need to end with ;
err=$?
# use [ ... ] (test), not ((...))
if [ "$err" -ne 5 ] && [ "$err" -ne 0 ]; then
  exit "$err"
fi
flake8
```

In the context of a CI system, it is important to remove the `volumes:` line that mounts a local directory over your container's `/app` directory: having that line means you are not testing what's in your image at all, but instead a possibly-related code tree that's on the host system.

In practice I'd suggest running both of these tools in a non-Docker environment.  It will be simpler to run them and collect their results.  Especially a style checker like `flake8` will have very few dependencies on system packages or other containers being started, and ideally your unit tests can also run without hard-to-set-up context like a database container as well.  I'd suggest a sequence like:

1. Check out the source code.
2. Create a virtual environment and install its dependencies.
3. Run `pytest`, `flake8`, and similar test tools.
4. Then build a Docker image, without test-only tools.
5. Run the image with its assorted dependencies.
6. Run further tests based on network calls into the container.